# SD card for Sony FDR-AX100E 4K?

Tags: camcorder, sd-card

I recently acquired a Sony FDR-AX100E.

**Samsung 64 Pro+, SDXC I 10 U3** says:

```
Cannot record. Please use UHS-I U3 compatible memory ...
```

**Sandisk Extreme Pro SDHC-1 U3 10 32Gb** says:

```
This memory card does not supoprt does not support recording ofXAVC S movies.
```

**Lexar Professional SDXC I U1** says

```
Cannot record. Please use UHS-I U3 compatible memory ...
```

But this latest is a U1 so this one makes sense. (I only recently discovered about U1 and U3.)

The manual says that to record XAVC S I need

```
Class 10 or faster, up to 64GB
```

Which card am I supposed to use ?

The camera has the latest firmware (3.00).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found regarding **Sandisk Extreme Pro SDHC-1 U3 10**
The card was formatted to FAT32, I reformatted the card to exFat (unit size 128kb, though I am not sure at all about the impact of unit size, that's something I'll have to check) .

What is really "fun" is that the camera itself can only format the card to FAT32 so I need to format it using a computer.

I'll keep this up to date.

Update:
Even re-formatted:  **Samsung 64 Pro+, SDXC I 10 U3** look like the camera won't recognize it as U3.